# load another one model in default model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to load another model in one default model. I have a **profiles** table in my database. but getting error.

**User model**

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');   
    class User extends AppModel {

          public function getProfileData(){
                $this->loadModel('Profile');
                $profileData = $this->Profile->findById('8');
                print_r($profileData);
            }
    }
```

**Error :**

```
 Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'loadModel' at line 1

SQL Query: loadModel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[loadmodel](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3aloadModel) works in controllers.

To use a new model in the current one, try:

```
App::uses('Profile', 'Model');
$Profile = new Profile();
$profileData = $Profile->findById('8');
```

Comment: ohk i have tried but now Error: Class 'Profile' not found .
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
App::uses('Profile', 'Model');
class User extends AppModel {
public function getProfileData(){
  $Profile = new Profile();
  $profileData = $Profile->findById('8');
  print_r($profileData);
 }
}

Comment: Is the Profile model working fine in the other places? Can you paste the first lines from it?

Comment: i didn't try it any where .. it is my first attempt with profile model.

Comment: if the profile model is ok, including it with `App::uses` will work. If you need any help with it, check http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html

Answer (score 1):

There is another way.

```
$profile= ClassRegistry::init('Profile');
$profileData = $profile->findById(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Profile model is associated with the User model already.
If that's the case, you can access it using:

```
$this->User->Profile->findById(8);
```

without the need to load anything.